# What is a good strategy for moving to Continuous Deployment?

Tags: web-development, continuous-delivery, devops

#### My Goal

I'm currently in the process of trying to get my company to adopt Continuous Deployment of the web product I work on. As far as I know, we're the first product in the company to attempt this. I'd like to know any pain points people have run into when moving to CD or tips people can give me who currently work at a job that uses CD. Is there a specific strategy you used to move your company to CD?

#### Steps I've taken:

In order to get my product ready for CD, I've taken several steps.

- Metrics, metrics, metrics. Because it's going to be a culture shift to go from deploying once every 3 months to daily, I know that I'll need data to support my ideas. I'm starting to track application performance, bugs per release, number of releases, and test coverage percentage.
- I built out a pipeline that can deploy to a small subset of production servers to make sure the release works without affecting a large number of users.
- I built out automated UI test suits

Does anyone have a specific strategy/actionable steps that they used to move their company to CD?
I'm also looking for any general advice/things to watch out for but that doesn't fit the Q/A format very well.

Comment: Changes to the way how people work in a team always require individual solutions, there is no "one-size-fits-all" approach to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit broad for this site (too many good answers as the question is phrased as I am writing this), but they key thing is people.

People will be your problem, not technology. Scared people, worried you will break things - fearful of the unknown. Give them a vision. Give them a plan. Give them incremental change. Find some allies so it’s not just your crazy idea.